# Typescript interface for object with array

Tags: typescript, interface

Trying to make an interface for an object that has an optional children field that has an array of the same interface.

```
export interface ItemInterface {
  name: string;
  id: number;
  children?: ItemInterface[];
}
```

This gives me an error of :
Type 'ItemInterface' must have a 'Symbol.iterator' method that returns an iterator.

Comment: [Does it?](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgSVQFt8U0tc4BvAKDjiUyOAC44BnGKZAcwG46iACZskAVyIAjNAPrYAFggA2QqMCQB+NoWAkyGHMADaAXQEBfGkA)  You should try to edit this question to provide a [mcve] of your issue, or else it is unlikely that anyone will be able to help you.  Good luck!

Comment: @jcalz Thanks solved it. I accidentally associated it incorrectly in my app.

Answer (score 0):

Accidentally associated the interface with an array - closing

Comment: Yeah, array vs non-array type error messages can be pretty hard to understand.